# Creating a service client in Fargate Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, credentials, aws-fargate

I am trying to build a service client within a Fargate task using a Task level IAM Role.

Posts elsewhere suggest the TaskRole is part of the default credentials provider chain so the standard call to load credentials should work.

Stripped down task code

```
import (
"fmt"
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/external"
"github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sns"
)

func main() {
    cfg, err := external.LoadDefaultAWSConfig()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to load config, " + err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", cfg )

    client := sns.New(cfg)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", client)
}
```

Terraform Role and Policy definitions...

TaskExecutions and TaskRole are essentially the same code albeit 2 blocks: (correct ??)

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "++++++++++++" {
  name = "++++++++++++++"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
      "Service": [
        "ecs.amazonaws.com",
        "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      ]
     },
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Task execution Policy

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "ExecutionPolicy" {
  name = "execution-policy"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
            "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
            "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
            "ecr:BatchGetImage",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
          ],
        "Resource": "*"
      }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Task Role Policy

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "TaskPolicy" {
  name = "task-policy"
  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "sns:Publish"
          ],
        "Resource": "*"
      }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Policies seem to be attached to the roles correctly and look ok on the console when the task is running.

I would expect the task to load the configuration/credentials from the IAM task role from a search of the default credentials provider chain and create a client.

However, the ONLY log result is :

**standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"**

When I run other code **without** calls to other aws services the task executes correctly.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Looks like an error loading the aws libraries. Raised an issue on GitHub